# how to calculate $f(D(0,\delta) - \{ 0 \})$ with $f(z)=z\sin(\frac{1}{z})$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

how to calculate $f(D(0,\delta) -  \{ 0 \})$ with $f(z)=z\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ ?.

I know that zero is an essential singularity, and so  $f(D(0,\delta)-\{ 0 \})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

This question  in this book Conway.

Comment: You can do better than that. The neighbourhood around an essential singularity misses at most one value.

Comment: I did not want to use the Picard theorem.

Comment: Let $R:={1\over\delta}$. Then it's about the function $g(\zeta):={\rm sinc}(\zeta)$ for $|\zeta|>R$. This is easier to visualize.